# Form data validation

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form that has a text box for Name, and the format is LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME.  How can I add a validation check to make sure the user enters a "," after the last name.

For example: Name: DOE, JOHN instead of DOE JOHN

Comment: In the field definition itself? Or by vba code in the form's before_update event? Update your question with the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of how you decide to validate the input you can use the `INSTR` function to test for the existence of the string `", "`

Here's the example of adding to the Table's definition of your field in the Validation Rule and Validation Message

**FIELD DEFINITIO**N

[image: Validation Rule Setup]

With the table showing error message if you try to enter a name without the ", "

**VALIDATION ERROR MESSAGE**

[image: Error Message]